# Functional programming dictionary character replace, keyboard layout fixer

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

Let say we want to fix text that was written on a AZERTY(or Dvorak, or another language layout) keyboard, as if it was a regular QWERTY one. We want to replace certain characters on corresponding ones.

So we have a dictionary, that looks similar to this:

```
const dic = {
q: a,
z: w,
}
```

But the dictionary is big, for every character. I'm searching for a way to do this not using for loops, using advantages of latest javascript changes, maybe with .replace() or .map() or anything you can suggest.

Comment: There's no other way than looping over the text. Whether you use `for`, `replace` or `map` doesn't really make a difference. The size of the dictionary does not matter - the whole point of using a lookup table is its `O(1)` access

Comment: Well, I just found [this project](https://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/). Not sure you're looking for a 3rd party library, but it seems to have a lot of the functionality you might want built-in for you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a big dictionary since a lot of the keys on `AZERTY` are in the same place: only make a map for the keys that are different and return the input if no mapping exists:

```js
const dict = {
  q: "a",
  w: "z"
  // e, r, t, y are in the same place, for example...
};

console.log(
  "qwerty".split("") // Explode the string to an array
       .map(letter => dict[letter] || letter) // Map inputs
       .join("") // output a string
);

// Generate a reverse mapping
const reverse_dict = {};
Object.keys(dict).forEach(key => reverse_dict[dict[key]] = key);

console.log(
  "azerty".split("")
       .map(letter => reverse_dict[letter] || letter)
       .join("")
);
```

Note that with arrow functions:

1. You do not need parenthesis around the parameter list if there is only one parameter.
2. If you omit the `{}` around the function body, you can also omit the `return` keyword and the body will return the value of the last (only) expression (save for a void parameter, which is a set of empty brackets `()` which you'll see in places like `setTimeout`).
3. A common misconception about `const` is that you can't update an array or object after it's initialized, but that's not the case. What you can't do is assign the variable to something else (like `const o = {}; o = ""`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. AZERTY keyboard was just an example. Also is there a quick way to do reverse change?

Comment: @StasIaremenko I imagined it was, but my point was that you don't need mappings of the form `v: "v"`. And yes: what you'd probably want to do is generate a reverse mapping at the start (store it if if really is big). I updated my example.

Comment: And what form of mapping would you suggest for such a purpose?

Comment: Also, is there any way to ignore case when replacing and save case at a final result? Will it take symbos in a form like "[": "&"?

Comment: @StasIaremenko I updated my answer with an example. But Bergi's comment is germane, there is just no way to do this (at least in JavaScript) without iterating over the array. The only O(1) lookup you get is from the dictionary you give `.map()`.

Comment: ES6 reverse dictionary one-liner: `Object.entries(dict).reduce((reverseDict, [newValue, newKey]) => Object.assign(reverseDict, { [newKey]: newValue }), {})`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Nicer :) I'll update it. I haven't delved into the new `Object` accessors much yet.

Comment: Also note the array destructure in the `reduce()` callback, and the computed property key

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Destructuring is one of my favourite things. In fact, why don't you post another answer?

Comment: @msanford because you already answered it, and I can't think of a "more elegant" way to deal with the verbose mapping between keyboards.